# Reading columns from Excel, reformat cells

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection, oledbdataadapter

I am currently trying to read in cells from an excel spread sheet, and it seems to reformat cells when I don't want it to.  I want it to come through as plan text.  I have read a couple of solutions to this problem and I have implemented them, but I am still having the same issue.

The reader turns dates in numbers and numbers into dates.

Example:

> Friday, January 29, 2016 comes out to be : 42398
>
> and
>
> 40.00 comes out to be : 2/9/1900 12:00:00 AM

code:

```
string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + files[0] + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;IMEX=1;HDR=NO;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"";
try {
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(stringconn);
    OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [CUAnswers$]", conn);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    try {
        printdt(dt);
```

I have tried

```
IMEX=0;
HDR=NO;
TypeGuessRows=1;
```

This is how I am printing out the sheet

```
public void printdt(DataTable dt) {
        int counter1 = 0;
        int counter2 = 0;
        string temp = "";
        foreach (DataRow dataRow in dt.Rows) {
            foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray) {
                temp += " ["+counter1+"]["+counter2+"]"+ item +", ";
                counter2++;
            }
            counter1++;
            logger.Debug(temp);
            temp = "";
            counter2 = 0;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem, except it was using Interop to read the Excel spreadsheet. This worked for me:

```
var value = (range.Cells[rowCnt, columnCnt] as Range).Value2;
string str = value as string;
DateTime dt;
if (DateTime.TryParse((value ?? "").ToString(), out dt))
{
    // Use the cell value as a datetime
}
```

Editted to add new ideas

I was going to suggest saving the spreadsheet as comma-separated values. Then Excel converts the cells to text. It is easy to parse a CSV in C#.

That led me to think of how to programmatically do the conversion, which is covered in [Convert xls to csv programmatically](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b2867f69-e98d-479d-9f8d-865348c589c5/convert-xls-to-csv-programmatically-and-back-again?forum=adodotnetdataproviders). Maybe the code in the accepted answer is what you are looking for:

```
string ExcelFilename = "c:\\ExcelFile.xls";
DataTable worksheets;
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + @"Data Source=" + ExcelFilename + ";" + @"Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1""";
using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    worksheets = connection.GetSchema("Tables");
    foreach (DataRow row in worksheets.Rows)
    {
        // For Sheets: 0=Table_Catalog,1=Table_Schema,2=Table_Name,3=Table_Type
        // For Columns: 0=Table_Name, 1=Column_Name, 2=Ordinal_Position
        string SheetName = (string)row[2];
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(@"SELECT * FROM [" + SheetName + "]", connection);
        OleDbDataAdapter oleAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        oleAdapter.SelectCommand = command;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        oleAdapter.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Source);
        oleAdapter.Fill(dt);
        for (int r = 0; r < dt.Rows.Count; r++)
        {
           string type1 = dr[1].GetType().ToString();
           string type2 = dr[2].GetType().ToString();
           string type3 = dr[3].GetType().ToString();
           string type4 = dr[4].GetType().ToString();
           string type5 = dr[5].GetType().ToString();
           string type6 = dr[6].GetType().ToString();
           string type7 = dr[7].GetType().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help.  I don't want to re-convert it.  I want it to come out of the cell in the correct format.  or just as plan text.

Comment: It seems to me if you want to read a cell as a string, then it needs to be entered as a string and not as a datetime (or whatever). You may need to alter the spreadsheet and convert those cells to text, possibly by prefixing the value with a single quote. (That is probably not the answer you wanted.)